# Django Music Application

Tags: django

I am trying to write an application in Django that allows producers to share their music samples and download samples from others. I was curious if this is possible with Django's built in functionalities or if I would be better suited using something like rails or Node js.

Comment: What all inbuilt functionalities are you referring to ?

Comment: basically an application that is superior to Splice.com that allow users to POST their samples and GET other peoples samples. Additionally, you will have your own storage for all the samples that you have uploaded as well as samples that you have downloaded.

Comment: I guess, some microframework like Flask will also suffice for your need of POST and GET

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sort of app is what Django excels at.

Comment: Would the ideal database be postgres and the ideal server be apache?

Comment: Nginx as the frontend server + Postgres as database is what I use.

Comment: It would. It doesn't matter that much.

Comment: I was just wondering which one has more documentation and tutorials for integrating with postgres

Comment: The web server doesn't matter that much with Django. Nginx is easier to configure and I dare say faster. Using Postgres with Django is thoroughly documented in the Django manual.

Comment: If I wanted to set up the web server with django and postgres where would I go for documentation on that?

Comment: Don't worry about the web server now. With Django, you do 99% of your development work using the Django `devserver ` anyway. You can follow the Django tutorials and documentation on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ .

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Also, would it be worth using node js with django or will django work for the whole site? Also, I want to port this to mobile and desktop and was wondering if that is possible with django.

Comment: Django will work fine for the whole site. If you mean mobile and desktop native apps, you can use Django as just an API server for those.

Comment: So the structure of the app can stay the same and I can just port it to mobile and desktop with an API?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You'll share the database structure (models in Django) and serve them differently for web users and API users.

Comment: sorry one more question. What if I want to have all of these samples from my desktop, mobile, and web app filtered in through a VST plugin that can be loaded into a DAW. Can django's API work with JUCE to make this happen?

Comment: Django isn't related to that, really. So long as you can load data over HTTP(S) within JUCE (which I'm sure you can), yes.

Comment: does apache work as a reverse proxy and load balancer if I decide to go that route instead of the nginx route?